# How to update a view on a scheduled period

Tags: android, multithreading, view, timer, android-windowmanager

Can some one please tell me how to update a view on a scheduled period. for example every second.

```
MyService.wm.updateViewLayout(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

Problem that I'm having is when I used a timer it run on different thread and it is not allow me to update the view and give following error.

> 04-08 01:19:35.910: W/dalvikvm(11040): threadid=13: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3e1f8) 04-08 01:19:35.910:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11040): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1376 04-08
>   01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   04-08 01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039) 04-08
>   01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709) 04-08
>   01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):    at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12680) 04-08 01:19:35.910:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11040):  at
>   android.view.View.setLayoutParams(View.java:8223) 04-08 01:19:35.910:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11040):  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:312)
>   04-08 01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:145)
>   04-08 01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):  at
>   com.example.MyService.UpdateLayers(TrackerService.java:353)
>   04-08 01:19:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11040):  at
>   com.example.MainActivity$5$1.run(MainActivity.java:219)

When I'm trying to update it from the same Activity or service it hangs and not do any thing else. just running in the loop.

```
while (true) {
    MyService.UpdateLayers();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, can you please tell me the correct way to do this or work around to update the layers.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with a Handler. You define a Handler on your main thread like this.-

```
protected Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case DO_SOME_VIEW_CHANGES:
            {
                // Your logic
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, you need to create a Thread that receives your handler instance, and call inside it.-

`handler.sendEmptyMessage(DO_SOME_VIEW_CHANGES);`

Hope it helps.